# Remove Background in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, background-removal, bitmap

I have two versions of a black and white image and would like to remove the background in both. I used Trace Bitmap in Inkscape with the settings below - the white background was no problem, but in the black image it keeps removing the white part that I want to keep. Any ideas how I can switch this, or another way to remove the black background and keep the white logo? Thanks!

[image: The left ones are the jpegs I have, the traced bitmaps on the right]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select *Invert image* in the *Trace Bitmap* dialogue.
2. Perform the trace. You will first obtain your logo in black (like in the first case).
3. Open the *Fill and Stroke* dialogue (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and change colour of the result to white (or whatever you like).

Alternatively:

1. Trace like you did in the example.
2. Draw a rectangle around the inverted logo, but inside the traced rectangle.
3. Move the new rectangle behind the logo (<kbd>End</kbd>).
4. Select both the rectangle and the logo (e.g., using a rectangle selection).
5. *Path → Difference.*

Answer (score 1):

When tracing bitmaps, Inkscape doesn't see the black as a background. It sees white as the background, and black as the ink.

The trace of the bottom image shows a black square with the letters and logo cut out as if the white is the background.  You don't need to do any of this. Simply copy the trace you achieved with the top image, and set the fill to white.  Then you will be able to place it on a darker background.

If you only have a reversed out version of a logo to trace, then you could use the "invert image" option as suggested by @Wrzlprmft.

Answer (score -2):

To get optimal results then it is best to approximate the specific vector that is queued for rendering prior to any linear vector layer transfers. It can be utilized in two ways: Firstly, the output level histogram and the primary source beacons need consideration if the input has exceeded any thresholds in the matrix resampling. I'm not sure of the second way.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design. Unfortunately, I fail to make sense of your answer. Can you please [edit] it to elaborate how it connects to the question and how to do any of the things you mention with Inkscape?