# Remove background of a single contiguous color

Tags: inkscape, background-removal

I have a PNG image which has two figures, bounded by black lines, against a purely white background.
My figures have also some white *"pixels"* (dots, points) inside, not contiguous with background *"pixels"*. Use of the word *pixel* is not meant to be technically strict.
I mean to get an image with transparent instead of white background, same as if it were generated from the get-go, by removing all contiguous white *pixels*. This seems something attainable.
Preferably with Inkscape.

I tried [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/15566/130540), but the result was not good.

Later I found

[Remove Background in Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92412/remove-background-in-inkscape?rq=1)

Comment: If you have pixels, then you are surely working with raster (pixel-based) images, not vector graphics. Inkscape is a tool for vector graphics.

Comment: @Juancho - I mentioned pixels but I am not sure I have them, I am importing png files into Inkscape.

Comment: PNGs are raster images, not vector. If you import them into Inkscape, they are still raster images. Use a raster image editor instead.

Comment: @BillyKerr - So you mean that removing the contiguous background region of a given single color (white here) is not possible with PNGs in Inkscape?

Comment: I mean you can't edit pixels in Inkscape, and there is no way to select any pixels in a raster image and modify them. You could add a vector clipping path to a raster image, but it's manual work - literally drawing a path around the image.

Comment: Agreeing with Billy. You should also make clear, what are you actually looking for. I sent a post about removing white background and it turns out you're perhaps looking for tracing (according to edit you made later)? If you really want to remove a background, then follow my post. Gimp is for free opensource and completes Inkscape's vector world with bitmap processing. You can do background removal with tracing, but it's a *different process*, where you end up with scallable graphics made from a bitmap source. For removing white background, it's like using a machine gun to hunt birds...

Comment: Note: your recent edit and link is for auto tracing a raster image, which is not the same as editing a png, or editing pixels in a png. The result would be vector, not raster.

Comment: @BillyKerr - So the only way to attain the objective, with Inkscape, is drawing the contour by hand?
I guess Gimp is an alternative for automated processing.

Comment: @sancho.s: Catching your comment about automated processing, I modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your desire to work in Inkscape, that is OK, however, I would edit the imported PNG in bitmap editor first, then use it in Inkscape for vector-like work.

For example in Gimp:

1) Open bitmap file

2) In the layers, right-click the only layer there and select "Add alpha channel" (this will allow transparency)

2) Click magic stick selection tool

3) Click to the white area (or more, with shift) you want to make transparent and press delete

4) Press CTRL+E for exporting edited bitmap and save as new PNG.

5) Use that PNG in Inkscape.

**EDIT:**

You've mentioned automated processing in your comment. You *can* do automated processing with **GIMP** (https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). However I haven't done that before; even though I use GIMP for desktop editing, I used ImageMagic for batch conversions.

Here is how you batch-remove background with **ImageMagic**:
https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#bg_remove